# Is is possible to insert comments into a long command with escaped newlines?

Tags: command-line, bash, comments

I have a long command line, longer than but similar to the example below. I would like to add comments to individual argument in the sense of what is shown here:

```
ssh -N \
    -R :10000:10.0.0.1:80 \ # test system
    -R :10001:10.0.0.2:80 \ # integration system
    -R :10002:10.0.0.3:80 \ # database foo
    -R :10003:10.0.0.4:80 \ # some other server
    example.com
```

But this sadly does not work as the `\` characters here no longer escape the newlines. Instead it escapes the space in front of the `#` an thus prevents the `#` from being parsed as the start of a comment (`#` may not appear inside of a token if it should be parsed as the start of a comment).

This also doesn't work because here, instead of the `\` escaping the `#`, the `#` now prevents the `\` from being interpreted.

```
-R :10000:10.0.0.1:80 # test system \
```

Is there any way to somehow mix comments and command line arguments (maybe on individual lines) of a single, long command? If not, what would you suggest I do to somehow associate the data passed to the command with commends to describe it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this StackOverflow question [Bash: How to Put Line Comment for a Multi-line Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522631/bash-how-to-put-line-comment-for-a-multi-line-command) comes [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797512/225906):

---

Essentially by using bash's backtick [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) one can place these comments anywhere along a long command line even if it is split across lines. I have put the echo command in front of your example so that you can execute the example and see how it works.

```
echo CommandName InputFiles `#1st comment` \
             --option1 arg1 `#2nd comment` \
             --option2 arg2 `#3rd comment`
```

Another example where you can put multiple comments at different points on one line.

```
some_cmd --opt1 `#1st comment` --opt2 `#2nd comment` --opt3 `#3rd comment`
```

Comment: This is both ugly and beautiful at the same time! And it's more robust than the solution I found in the meantime, which is inserting `: foo comment` inside backticks.